# How to break a loop at certain stage

Tags: c#

I have a matrix (int[8,8]) with binary digits in it.

I'm trying to write on the Console the leftmost column number, so that three 1 are available in the matrix from the left side of this column number (reading from top to bottom, left to write). For example - in below the column number will be 2 (indexes of the columns are from 0 to 7):

> 00000000
>   01000000
>   10000000
>   01000000
>   00101000
>   00000110
>   00000010
>   00000000

I use this code, but it is not working and I'm already stuck with it:

```
for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
    {
        int counter=0;
        if (matrix[row, column] == 1)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        if (counter==3)
        {
            break;
            Console.WriteLine(column);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Console.WriteLine(column) should be before break; statement in order to be executed, fyi.

Answer (score 1):

Above solutions breaks only the inner loop where the counter gets increased and continues to run the rest of the lopps (outer and inner without increasing the counter - ones it reaches 3 it remains 3 and continues to process the rest of the jobs considering that the counter is 3) 
Thus it gives a result on the console from 1 (the first column where the counter was 3) to 7 (till the last column). 
How to break the loops in such a way that it gives me only one line as a result and to break both loops ones counter gets 3?

Answer (score 0):

You counter should be outside the inner loop and Console.WriteLine before the break:

```
        for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++)
        {
            int counter=0;
            for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
            { 
                if (matrix[row, column] == 1)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
                if (counter==3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(column);
                    break;
                }
            }                    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your counter outside both loops and the break after the Console.Writeline

```
        var counter=0;
        for (var column = 0; column < 8; column++)
        {
            for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++)
            { 
                if (matrix[row, column] == 1)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
                if (counter==3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(column);
                    break;
                }
            }                    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think is better first check the count in the second step use counter++ this help you to do  lower action

```
 int counter=0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
        { 
            if (matrix[row, column] == 1)
            {
                if (counter==3)
                  {
                    Console.WriteLine(column);
                    break;

                  }
                else
                  {
                   counter++;
                  }
            }


        }
```